# Kafka Connect - connectors stop after no data for some time

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I am running Kafka Connect in distributed mode on Kubernetes with 3 sink connectors, Kafka -> S3.

When data flows into Kafka and at least one of the connectors has data to read, everything works fine.

But on periods when there is no data to read, for a few hours for example, and none of the connectors needs to read any data, all the connectors stop (the /connectors endpoint on the Rest API shows an empty list). So when new data comes in eventually - it is not read unless manually starting the connectors.

Is this common behavior or am I missing something? I can add additional information about the setup if needed.

Comment: Sounds like you're not hitting the correct instance of the API (when you say 3, that is pods? If so, you've not configured the Connect cluster correctly) Connectors do not stop unless you explicitly send a HTTP delete request

Comment: What do you mean by "not hitting the correct instance of the API"? There are 3 pods in the ReplicaSet. There are also 3 connectors (unrelated to the ReplicaSet size) which I start using Terraform. Everything works fine when the data flows. Only when all the connectors are idle for a few hours they suddenly all stop. I agree that if it was related to the connector itself, then the behavior of one would not affect the others.

Comment: Only one instance of the Connect cluster is the leader. When you get an empty list, that means that instance you've reached from the load balancer is either unable to reach the leader, or the pod thinks it's part of its own cluster and therefore is its own leader with zero connectors

Comment: To test this, scale the replica set to one instance, then see if there are zero connectors when the data is idle

Comment: First, thank you for your explanation - I will test it. Do you mean that the connectors are basically still up but I'm just not seeing it in the API?

Comment: Based on my experience, unless something changed past Kafka 2.4, then connectors aren't deleted. The consumers just idly poll

Comment: Tried scaling down to 1 for the weekend. The connectors have stayed on even after a few hours of idleness. However, on some point they disappeared. Is it possible that due to a pod restart that occurred - I have to manually restart the connectors?

Comment: Assuming you're running  Connect distributed mode in the container, then the configurations are all stored in Kafka topics. The only way those would be deleted is if those topics aren't configured as compact, or the Kafka topic data directories are being deleted

Comment: I am running on distributed mode in the container.
It looks like the "config.storage.topic" topic is not configured as "cleanup.policy=compact". Is that what you mean? Should I change that?

Comment: According to the documentation, yes, it needs to be compacted https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#connect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on comments, your `config.storage.topic` was not created with `cleanup.policy=compact`, therefore Kafka is deleting your configs for *idle configurations*, not idle connector tasks. When the configs are deleted from the topic, then the REST API removes the `/connector` response information.

Refer documentation on appropriate configurations for the internal Connect topics

https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#connect

Comment: This worked for me. Thank you for your elaborated explanation and patience.